# Trouble accessing value from knockout.js select list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I can't access value from a knockout.JS select list

```
<select data-bind="value: cardType,
    optionsCaption: '--',
    options: $root.cardTypeList,
    optionsText: 'type'"></select>

self.cardTypeList = [{type: 'Visa'},
    {type: 'MasterCard'},
    {type: 'American Express'}];
self.cardType = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true });
```

I've tried the following ways to retrieve the value selected, and these are the responses when I used alert to display them.

```
self.cardType()                     //displays [object object]
self.cardType                       //displays a whole bunch of javascript
self.cardTypeList[self.cardType()]  //displays undefined
```

If I select MasterCard from the list and then use `alert(self.cardType().toSource())` in firefox it shows `({type:"MasterCard"})`

I know it's being set, I just don't know how to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cardTypeList` is a list of object so, to access selected `cardType` you should do,

```
 var yourSelectedCardType = self.cardType().type;
```